# ¿Como incializar un input en angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy usando la libreria `NgxIntlTelInput` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-intl-tel-input) para apoyar y obtener unos codigos de area de telefono. Pues bien, resulta que quiero inicializar este input con la respuesta de la api que almaceno en una variable, pero hasta el momento no lo he logrado ¿Alguna recomendación de como podría realizarlo?

**.HTML**

```html
<mat-form-field class="mt-12" appearance="outline" style="width: 90%;">
  <label>Para:</label>
  <!-- <input [formControlName]="i" placeholder="City"> -->
  <ngx-intl-tel-input class="flex-grow-1 " cssClass="form-control phoneInput" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries " [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false " [enablePlaceholder]="true " [searchCountryFlag]="true
                                        " [searchCountryField]="searchCountryField " searchCountryPlaceholder="Buscar País" [selectFirstCountry]="false " [selectedCountryISO]="initialCountry " [separateDialCode]="true " [phoneValidation]="true " inputId="phoneInput"
    name="phone" [formControl]="phoneControl" [formControlName]="i" (change)="getValues()" required>
    <input matInput type="text " class="ng-dirty ng-invalid " required/>
  </ngx-intl-tel-input>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let contacto of filteredContactos | async" [value]="contacto.telefonos[0]">
      {{contacto?.telefonos[0]}} {{contacto?.nombre_completo ? '('+ contacto?.nombre_completo +')' : ''}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

**.TS**

```
clienteTel:string[]=[];

  formsB = new FormGroup({
    cities: new FormArray([
      new FormControl(this.clienteTel),
    ]),
  });
 envioSMSForm: FormGroup;

getTelefonoCliente() {
    this.mantenimientosService.obtenerCliente(this.data.solicitud.cliente_id).subscribe((cliente) => {
      this.clienteTel = cliente.telefono;
      //console.log('testvariable', this.telCliente);
    })
  }

  addCity() {
    this.cities.push(new FormControl());
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.cities.value.map(map => map.e164Number));  // este te trae el enmascarado del numero
    console.log(this.formsB.value);    // { cities: ['SF', 'NY'] }
  }

  setPreset() {
    this.cities.patchValue(['LA', 'MTV']);
  }

  addLesson() {
    this.numbersForm = this.fb.group({
      tel: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.numbers.push(this.numbersForm);
  }

  deleteLesson(lessonIndex: number) {
    this.cities.removeAt(lessonIndex);
  }
```

Lo que hice fue primero hacer un método `getTelefonoCliente` para obtener el télefono del usuario, lo almacene en una variable y luego este método lo llamo en el `ngOnInit` del componente, luego tengo estructurado un `FormGroup` (formulario reactivo) y alli quiero inicializar la variable que tiene almacenada la `Res` de la api, pero no me funciona

Lo que aun no descrubro es si tiene que ver que la `Res` yo la estoy recibiendo como un `['']` , es decir un arreglo de strings y por eso la inicialización no me funciona, o alguna otra cosa. Aunque cuando lo paso a string sigue sin funcionarme, o será tal vez la manera es que estoy tratando de inicializar

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo? Porfavor, muchas gracias de antemano por toda su ayuda.

Comment: Estoy tratando de entender para poder ayudarte, este paquete no te crea ya un input con todo? porque razon buscar el telefono mediante un servicio?

Comment: Hola @GersonnVelasquez no lo que pasa, es que lo único que quiero hacer es inicializar el input de este paquete. Es decir que cuando yo inicie el componente el input venga con el numero que justo viene de un objeto (res).